# Is "Symmetric mean absolute surface distance" (SMAD) used for 2D images or 3D images?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am not sure if the "Symmetric mean absolute surface distance" (SMAD) is used as a metric to evaluate the segmentation algorithm for 2D images or 3D images? Thanks!

Comment: You should provide some references and links to clarify what you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry, I have no knowledge in this field, and so I cannot find a reference.

Answer (score 2):

#### What are surface Distance based metrics?

- [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance)
- Hausdorff distance 95% percentile
- Mean (Average) surface distance
- Median surface distance
- Std surface distance

**Note**: These metrics are **symmetric**, which means the distance from A to B is the same as the distance from B to A.

For each contour voxel of the segmented volume (A), the Euclidean distance from the closest contour voxel of the reference volume (B) is computed and stored as `list1`. This computation is also performed for the contour voxels of the reference volume (B), stored as `list2`. `list1` and `list2` are merged to get `list3`.

- `Hausdorff distance` is the maximum value of `list3`.
- `Hausdorff distance 95% percentile` is the 95% percentile of `list3`.
- `Mean (Average) surface distance` is the mean value of `list3`.
- `Median surface distance` is the median value of `list3`.
- `Std surface distance` is the standard deviation of `list3`.

**References:**

1. Heimann T, Ginneken B, Styner MA, et al. Comparison and Evaluation of Methods for Liver Segmentation From CT Datasets. IEEE Transactions on Medical Imaging. 2009;28(8):1251–1265.
2. Yeghiazaryan, Varduhi, and Irina D. Voiculescu. "Family of boundary overlap metrics for the evaluation of medical image segmentation." Journal of Medical Imaging 5.1 (2018): 015006.
3. Ruskó, László, György Bekes, and Márta Fidrich. "Automatic segmentation of the liver from multi-and single-phase contrast-enhanced CT images." Medical Image Analysis 13.6 (2009): 871-882.

## How to calculate the surface distance based metrics?

[`seg-metrics`](https://github.com/Jingnan-Jia/segmentation_metrics) is a simple package to compute different metrics for **Medical** image segmentation(images with suffix `.mhd`, `.mha`, `.nii`, `.nii.gz` or `.nrrd`), and write them to csv file.

I am the author of this package.

Comment: Could I use seg-metrics  in memory without writing result to csv?

Comment: @user836026 Of course. Default setting is in-memory results. Only if you set the `csv_file`, you can save the results to disk.

Comment: Could I pass the whole batch at once or in need to pass them one by one? @Jingnan Jia

Comment: @user836026 You could pass they by a whole batch by loading them from disk of two different directories. Or if you only have them in-memory, you can also apply our package one by one using a for loop.

Comment: I notice when I call it, it prints some output like this (inside the loop): "0it [00:00, ?it/s]
1it [00:00,  5.06it/s" ... is there a way to get rid of this output.

Comment: @user836026 You just need to set 'verbose' as 'False'. For example, 

sg.write_metrics(label = ......[fill the required input] , verbose=False)

Comment: @user836026 Thanks for your feedback. Now I have already change the default 'verbose' as 'False' in the latest version v1.1.6. So if you "pip install seg-metrics --upgrade", then you can use the latest package and avoid the annoying information like "0it [00:00, ?it/s] 1it [00:00, 5.06it/s" in default.

Answer (score 0):

I found two papers which address the definitions of SMAD:

- https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/7732/CS-RR-15-08.pdf (see section 7.1 on average symmetric surface distance, but this is the same thing)
- http://ai2-s2-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/2b8b/079f5eeb31a555f1a48db3b93cd8c73b2b0c.pdf (page 1439, see equation 7)

I tried to post the equation here but I do not have enough reputation.  Basically look at equation 15 in the first reference listed above.

It appears that this is defined for 3D voxels, though I don't see why it should not work in 2D.